# Is there any disk supports parallel reading?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, disk

Reading files using multiple threads on a multi core system does it increases performance?
Is any disk supports parallel access?( not cuncurent access)

Comment: Can you explain your expectations a little more?  Disks typically have one set of read heads, so it's impossible to be reading from more than a cylinder at a time.  They typically have one set of "read electronics", making it impossible to read from more than one track at a time.  There's a single data path (bus) from the disk to memory, so there is only one inflight transfer at a time. So what's your expectation for "parallel access"?    Queued requests in the onboard disk controller?

Answer (score 2):

It makes a difference on both SSDs and spinning disks, but largely for different reasons.

For SSDs, if requests come from a single thread, there will be a dead time after the SSD has retrieved the data for one request and before the thread can send its next request. This dead time can be a significant fraction of the SSD's read time because SSDs are so fast.

For spinning disks, the order in which reads are executed can matter. For example, if a read is issued for track 1, track 12, and track 2, it can be more efficient to perform the read for track 2 before the read for track 12. But this cannot happen if the read for track 2 doesn't get issued until after a thread processes the results of the read from track 12.

In the case of SSDs, multiple cores help a lot more than mulitiple threads do. In the case of spinning disks, multiple threads can issue multiple reads that can be re-ordered even if they all have to share the same core.

Comment: Your answer implicitly answers my comment for request for clarification above.  I find "parallel reading" to be an odd way to describe command queueing since the reads are obviously serialized. Is that a common usage?  (Answer upvoted, FWIW)

Comment: @another-dave IMO, so long as more than one read is "in flight" at a time, it's parallel reading. That is, so long as you don't wait for the result of one read to issue the next read, it's at least potentially parallel.

Comment: Note also that modern disks don't read sectors.  They read tracks, so the whole track might be sucked into the disk's internal cache, and if you happen to have two threads want data from the same track, it's already there for the second thread.